# PHP lcfirst not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to lowercase the first letter of my title.

```
<title><?php echo lcfirst(bloginfo('name')); ?>.blog</title>
```

> - This **should** result into: super.blog
> - But results into: Super.blog

I have tried:

```
<title><?php 
$bloginfo = bloginfo('name');
echo lcfirst($bloginfo);
?>.blog</title>
```

How is this possible? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Most like the first character is not what you think it is. Use urlencode as an easy way to see what byte values it contains.

Comment: Try doing `lcfirst(trim($data))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In wordpress, the function `bloginfo` `echo`s the result. Use `get_bloginfo` instead.

See code below for the `bloginfo` function.

```
function bloginfo( $show = '' ) {
    echo get_bloginfo( $show, 'display' );
}
```

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/

Comment: That's strange. Well, I've changed it to `get_bloginfo('name')` and now it works. Thanks for the useful information!